# How to highlight graphql template literals (gql) in js(x) files?

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting, js2-mode

Inside of a jsx file, I want to use a `gql` template literal to define GraphQL queries.

Could I in emacs make that section of the jsx file highlight graphql syntax, instead of just showing it as a plain string?

Example:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const normalJavascriptCode = 42

const query = gql`
  here(a: 1, b: 2) {
    itWouldHighlightSyntax
    accordingToGraphQLMode
  }
`

const jsHighlightBackagain = () => {...}
```

Here you can see how it works for atom: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/123#issuecomment-244830016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution using the emacs package `mmm-mode`. Most of the information I got was from [this article](https://vxlabs.com/2014/04/08/syntax-highlighting-markdown-fenced-code-blocks-in-emacs/).

What this package does, is allow multiple *major modes* in the same buffer. You basically set the opening and closing clauses for whatever nested syntax you have, and that block will be highlighted in a submode.

```
M-x package-install RET graphql-mode
M-x package-install RET mmm-mode
```

```lisp
(require 'graphql-mode)
(require 'mmm-mode)

(mmm-add-classes
    '((js-graphql
          :submode graphql-mode
          :face mmm-declaration-submode-face
          :front "[^a-zA-Z]gql`" ;; regex to find the opening tag
          :back "`"))) ;; regex to find the closing tag
(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'js-mode nil 'js-graphql)
(setq mmm-global-mode 'maybe)
;; Optional configuration that hides the background color for a highlighted block
;; I find it useful for debugging emacs, but when actually coding I dont want so much emphasis on submodes
(setq mmm-submode-decoration-level 0)
```

There are a lot of configuration options, but for this setup, you can re-highlight your blocks in an open buffer by running this command

```
M-x mmm-parse-buffer
```